# Single-label domain names

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-name

Does single-label domain name mean a name like 'OurHouse'.  Where as guy.ourhouse.com would not be a single-label domain.  If so, would guy-ourhouse.com be a multi-label domain name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is (99%) correct.

What confuses it in a strict technical sense is the implicit '.' on the end of every domain name (at least in the underlying DNS wire protocol) which is a zero length label.  However unless you're writing DNS software you don't need to worry about that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A single-label domain name is where a particular server is just called 'guy' for instance, not 'guy.com' or 'www.guy.com' - just a basic name. Setting up clients to deal with single-label domains is more trouble than it's worth - it's all a bit 'old hat' to be honest, best avoided.

Comment: I appreciated your answer

Comment: The following TLDs have A records: ac, ai, bi, cm, dk, gg, hk, io, je, mn, ph, pn, pw, sh, tk, tm, to, uz, and ws. I didn't look for three letter tlds.  This is on the IPv4 network that people commonly call "the internet" using the commonly accepted root name servers.